# SQLite database after unistall the app from device

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one question .

I am  using SQLite database ,if i uninstall the app from my device database will be in device or it will removed automatically.

and if i again install the same app again what will happen.

Comment: If you uninstall application from device means SQLite db also deleted.again it will created whenever you install the application

Comment: are u sure pinki..any link can you provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQlite databases are just files, and they're treated like any other file: they're stored (by default) in the application's private data area (`/data/data/$PACKAGENAME/databases`). They're deleted along with everything else in the application's private data area.

You can create a database on the SD card if you like. They, of course, won't be removed on uninstallation.

**EDITED:**

Check this Database related example [HERE](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: i can see this database in my device or not.

Comment: Yes you can see the database in if you have stored it into the SDcard of your device. If you have stored your database in application memory of the device then you can't see it. Check out i have updated my answer.

Comment: i have stored it in my internal memory ..so i am not able to see it right?.

Comment: Yes if you have stored it into internal memory then you won't be able to see it. But if you want to see it then you can check it in eclipse from the `File Explorer`.

Comment: Welcome Adb. Happy to Help alwayz :)

Comment: grishu you work for vodafone ....Happy to help...hahaha just kidding man thanks again.